# Tension/gauge less prone to buzzing

Tags: guitar, strings, tone, string-gauge

**Is there a type of string (high tension or low tension) that is less prone to generate buzzing on the acoustic guitar ?**

I've mainly heard these few arguments so far :

- high tension strings are larger, making them more subjected to buzzing
- high tension strings have a lower amplitude of vibration when played, making them less subjected to buzzing
- the two effects above counterbalance each other making no real difference

Is one actually better than the other when specifically trying to avoid buzzing ?

Comment: Whatever tension or gauge strings are on at the time will have their propensity to buzz affected by the action and the string height - and to a degree the way the player presses them onto the fingerboard. So, for a given set of circumstances, there are still too many variables, I think, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Tim Of course, there are better ways of fixing buzzing than changing strings, but let's put that aside and focus only on this point : High or low tension and its interaction with buzzing. Or are you saying that this interaction behaves differently depending on other parameters, and it's not easily predictable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's knock the concepts into shape a bit…

1. high tension strings are larger, making them more subjected to buzzing

This makes no logical sense whatsoever. Sure, they're thicker, but the thickness still rests on the same fixed points, where the string passes over the nut, bridge & fretted position, meaning the bulk of the string is further from the fretboard not nearer.

2. high tension strings have a lower amplitude of vibration when played, making them less subjected to buzzing

Yes, to an extent. They won't vibrate quite so much for a given strike velocity.

However, assuming no other adjustment is made to the guitar, there is another reason they will not buzz…

3. They will pull the neck forward very slightly - giving better clearance to the next un-fretted fret, meaning less buzz.

This, combined with reason 2, would be the simplest explanation.

This assumes you can still correctly hold the string to the fret with the added tension & greater distance to the fretboard.

Comment: Nice, I totally didn't think of 1. when hearing the original arguments in my question. It makes sense though. Thanks :)